# setting fields by name on a class that have __slots__

Tags: python, slots

i have a python class that is defined using `__slots__`, like so:

```
class TheClass:
   __slots__=['foo','bar']
```

I would like to sets it values by name, like so

```
the_object=TheClass()
for x in ['foo','bar']: 
  the_object[x]=x+x
```

is that possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `__slots__`?

Comment: i like the idea of static typing - i want to know in advance what are the data members of my classes are. I think it help in understanding code

Comment: You'd use `setattr()`, or if you want to be obscure, use the slot descriptors: `TheClass.__dict__[x].__set__(the_object, x + x)`. But you don't, not really.

Comment: @yigalirani: Don't. Only use `__slots__` if you need to save memory; e.g. when you have *loads* of `TheClass` instances.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, why? are there some drawbacks for using __slots__?

Comment: @yigalirani: Python is dynamically typed, and many of its best features are built around that fact. Trying to force it to be otherwise means you're giving yourself the worst of both worlds.

Comment: @abarnert, any specific example? are there some code constructs that will fail if i use __slots_?

Comment: @yigalirani the most notable thing is that it breaks pickling.

Comment: @roippi: Yes. But more abstractly, it prevents you from designing your APIs around flexible duck-typing. If you have some function that naturally works with anything with a `foo` attribute that represents the amount of spam in the object, and has no interest in whether `bar` exists or what it means, you shouldn't write it in terms of a Java-style "interface" that has both `foo` and `bar`. (And even when such an interface is exactly what you need, it's usually the methods rather than the attributes that you care about, and [ABCs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) are the answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference with general case, you can use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
the_object=TheClass()
for attname in ['foo','bar']: 
    setattr(the_object, attname, attname+attname)
```

You'll get:

```
>>> the_object.foo
'foofoo'
```